# ClickOnce .net 5 Update Settings

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce, .net-5

Has anyone gotten Click Once updating after the application starts ? for me the option is grayed out after updating to .NET  5. I cant find any documentation on this new wizard there are a few issues I've run into ( things like the application files settings no longer exists. FTP no longer seems supported for deployment and the "when would you like to check for updates" radio buttons are all grayed out.)

Comment: I created a microsoft post here but i actually just found a much more in depth post which is visible here:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1288425/clickonce-no-longer-works.html.

Comment: Try to use your own account to report another problem both on [Developer Community .NET](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=61) and [Developer Community Visual Studio](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out as we move to .NET 5 there are several features that Microsoft is removing. if the option is grayed out it is no longer supported by .NET 5.... whish there had been some form of transparency on this